# Load Balancing Craft CMS - Admin gets logged out instantly

Tags: nginx, load-balancer

We are load balancing 2 servers hosting an identical Craft environment.

When clicking around in the admin a user will get logged out after 30 seconds and sometimes even faster when browsing in the admin panel.

I am unable to set the load balancer to sticky sessions due to the load balancer sitting behind a Firewall which NAT's inbound traffic. So the load balancer see's all inbound traffic as a single IP.

Is there anything else that can be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't enforce sticky sessions, then you'll need to provide a common place for all load balanced web server to save their PHP session files.

By default PHP session files are file based and saved to whatever path the php.ini [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) is set to.  You could change that to an NFS share path.

If you had an in-memory key=>value store (like Redis, Memcached, etc.) you could configure PHP to save its sessions there.

If you wanted something more persistent, you could configure PHP to save sessions in a database.

On top of that, if you're not using stick sessions, you'd want to set a consistent [appId](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#appId) and [validationKey](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#validationKey) across every web server so they can decrypt Craft/PHP cookies using the same tokens.

Comment: Hey Brad, we currently have php sessions saving to the generic /var/lib/php/session/ directory. NFS share path could be a possibility. We also use MemcacheD as our 'cacheMethod'. How would I go about setting php sessions to use MemcacheD? Both servers use the same cache server so that would be a common ground. We also currently have the appID and validationKey set consistent across all load balanced servers.  Thanks, Adam

Comment: You'd have to set a custom `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path`. Similar to examples here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-php-sessions-on-multiple-memcached-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks, just found a few of those tutorials.. Looks like there's a bug with php7 and or the version of memcacheD I'm using. Currrently getting : Failed to create session ID: memcached. With the hander and save_path set. I can create telnet connections from my web-server to my memcache servers just fine.